# "High inaccuracy" vs "low accuracy"

Tags: formality

Which one of the two forms "high inaccuracy" and "low accuracy" should be used in formal language? Is there a rule?
What about "highly inaccurate" vs "lowly accurate"?

Comment: It might help if you supply some context about how the terms will be used.

Comment: In the second pair, "highly inaccurate" is good and "lowly accurate" is definitely bad.

Comment: @KillingTime I heard the expression "high inaccuracy" in a documentary, in the context of guns accuracy. I'm not a native English speaker, but it didn't sound right.
On the other hand, "highly inaccurate" is a common expression, so I was wondering if there is a rule that makes the second one correct, but not the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"High inaccuracy" is not a likely phrase of the English language but "low accuracy" is a quite common one ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=High+inaccuracy%2Clow+accuracy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clow%20accuracy%3B%2Cc0)). To qualify a high level of inaccuracy the following phrases can be used (among other possible ones).

- [great inaccuracy](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great+inaccuracy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreat%20inaccuracy%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgreat%20inaccuracy%3B%2Cc0), [important inaccuracy](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=important+inaccuracy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimportant%20inaccuracy%3B%2Cc0)

On the contrary,"highly inaccurate" is commonly used whereas "lowly accurate" is not proper, as "lowly" means only "humble", "obscure, never "in a low level". You could say then "with a low level of accuracy", for instance.

Comment: You are right about "lowly accurate", maybe a better example would have been "barely accurate". However, I am really curious if there is a rule that dictates which combinations are correct. For example, apart from "high inaccuracy", I think that "barely inaccurate" is also invalid.

Comment: @ctapus I believe that your remark about "barely inaccurate" is right; it does not sound idiomatic to me; moreover, in my student's dictionary the following note can be found at the entry for "hardly": " 'hardly', barely' and 'scarcely' are negative words and should not be used with 'not' **or other negative words** (not correct: 'I can't hardly believe it.')". Except for those and possibly a few other rare cases, there is no rule: we are dealing here with idiomatic turns, collocations more precisely,, and those can't too often be justified on the grounds of the philosophy of English.